# jQuery function .on() doesn't work with "click" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working with MS Dynamics CRM 2013 and I am facing with the issue that when I want to add event handler to the button "Documents" in the navigation pane,

[image]

jQuery function .on() doesn't work with "click" event. It works fine with "mouseover" or "mouseup" events, but does not work with "click".
Here is code, that I'm using:

```
$("#crmMasthead").on( "click", "#Node_navDocument", function(){ alert("Success!"); } );

Where:
#crmMasthead - static selector;
#Node_navDocument - id of the button "Documents", that I want to reload.
```

Please help me with this issue. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is html which I am dealing with:

Before user opens navigation pane in CRM 2013:

```
<body>
...
    <div id="crmMasthead" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="navStatusArea" id="navStatusArea"></div>
        <div class='navBar' id='navBar'>...</div>       
        <div class="navBarOverlay" id="navBarOverlay" style="display: none;">     </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

User has just opened navigation pane in CRM 2013:

```
<body scroll="no">
...
    <div id="crmMasthead" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="navStatusArea" id="navStatusArea"></div>
        <div class='navBar' id='navBar'></div>
Changed:<div class="navBarOverlay" id="navBarOverlay" style="display: block;"></div>
New:    <div class="navActionGroupContainer" style="">
            ...
            <a class="navActionButtonContainer navActionButton     navActionButtonDefault normal " id="Node_navDocument" role="button" title="Documents" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on" style="background-color: #555555">...</a>
            ...
        </div>

    </div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Is `Node_navDocument` is child of `crmMasthead`? If not replace `crmMasthead` with `document`/respective parent element.

Comment: Why not to use click() ?
$("#crmMasthead").click(..)

Comment: If it works with `mouseup`, why not use that instead ? Something is probably blocking `click` events if other events are working.

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: @Tigran `$("#crmMasthead").click(..)`, as his code is effectively binding to the click of `#Node_navDocument`.

Comment: Open developer tool (Ctrl+Shift+J) in Chrome. And look at the element.  May be there is something above it.

Comment: Why are you using unsupported customization in CRM 2013? Which is the purpose of adding this event?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?  You might need to use delegate or bind if it's an older version.  Also note that you'll need to swap your selector and event around if you use delegate.

Comment: @Tigran: Because #Node_navDocument is representing "Documents" button and #crmMasthead represents next <div>:
`<div id="crmMasthead" tabindex="-1">` with several div's inside.

Comment: @adeneo Can you tell me, please, what can be the reason of this blocking? Because I need exactly "click" event.

Comment: @user5623896726 I am using jQuery 1.9.1. And .on() function works properly for "mouseover" and other events. Question is: "Why it doesn't work with "click"?"

Comment: @GuidoPreite I want to display specific IFrame after user clicks on "Documents" button on Contract entity.

Comment: @Unknown Yes, Node_navDocument is child of crmMasthead.

Comment: @Tigran About: "Open developer tool (Ctrl+Shift+J) in Chrome." Above `#crmMasthead` element is only `<body>`.  And I need to handle 'click' event for `#Node_navDocument`, that is child of `#crmMasthead` and does not exists in the context before user opens navigation pane in CRM 2013, look at the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @BrianWheeler I have just posted html in question. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, function .on() doesn't work with `click` event in my case because of event `click` of the `#Node_navDocument` element has already bound to another system function which uses `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and all custom logic doesn't execute after this.

But, there is another way...

Main goal of implementing custom logic for `click` event was displaying system `iframe` with different `src` link after this event. So, to resolve this task we need to do next:

[image]

- create handler for some static element (1) that should bound `onclick` event of element (2);
- create listener on `onclick` event of element (2) for watching if iframe exists or not.

Element (1) has id `#TabNode_tab0Tab`, element (2) - `#Node_navDocument` and iframe - 
`#areaDocumentFrame`.

Here is the code:

```
replaceDocumentsLink: function () {
    console.log("Function was started!");
    var listener = {};

    window.top.$("#TabNode_tab0Tab").on("mouseover", function () {
        if (window.top.$('#Node_navDocument').length)
            window.top.$('#Node_navDocument')[0].onclick = function () {
                listener = setInterval(function () {
                    if ($("#areaDocumentFrame").length) {
                        console.log("Frame was found!")
                        $("#areaDocumentFrame").attr("src", "http://www.microsoft.com/");                            
                        clearInterval(listener)
                    }
                    else
                        console.log("Frame was not found!")
                }, 250);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Accessing the DOM directly is unsupported in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: replaceDocumentsLink() may stop working in the future as the id #TabNode_tab0Tab may change (or any other id). The only safe way to interact with the form is through the Xrm.Page object. An alternative solution would have been to create a custom ribbon button and run a custom JavaScript function when the button is clicked. Using jQuery for AJAX is supported. Have a look here for more info on using jQuery in Dynamics CRM forms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx#BKMK_UsingjQuery

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#Node_navDocument', function() {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

Or

```
jQuery('#Node_navDocument').click(function() {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

Comment: About first: 
Unfortunately, it doesn't work with 'click' event, but it works with "mouseover" and other.
About second: #Node_navDocument doesn't exists in form context before navigation pane appears.

Comment: This helped me for another issue with binding, also needed to add function(e){e.preventDefault();} to make it work good.

Answer (score -1):

Delegation, as explained [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), is the way, and you are doing well.

As you can see in this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXW2B/), where the load of second div is simulated with a button, your code works.

By the way, maybe you have done like:

```
    $("#crmMasthead").on('click', function() {
       $(this).append("<div id=\"Node_navDocument\"> B </div>");
    });
```

If you use append, when you click on "#Node_navDocument", probably is called again code above and not:

```
   $("#crmMasthead").on('click', "#Node_navDocument", function() {
          .......
   });
```

## edit

Try to check z-index of the element. Maybe you have something else above your div.
This other [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VXW2B/2/) maybe can help you.

## edit 2 *after post html*

Note that you are binding click on a tag (with id Node_navDocument).  By the way, be sure you have not put ​​any preventDefault() on click event!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'am not using append, `#Node_navDocument` appears in the context after user opens navigation pane (here works internal CRM 2013 logic) like I mentioned in the screenshot, and other event handlers except 'click' work fine.

Comment: "appears".. maybe if you post some html to undertand div hierarchy we can help you.. btw take a look ad edit

Comment: I have just posted html in question. Please, take a look.

Comment: I don't know, it wasn't me.

Comment: But still I am interesting in solving of this issue. Unfortunately, your edit didn't help me.

Comment: I'm looking right know html... have you try removing "unselectable="on"" from tag A? (: